# Retrofit Post method throws error

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm making POST request with retrofit and it throws fatal signal error, but it only happens when I add callback with `onResonse, onFailure` methods if I call `.execute` method instead `.enqueue` it works without a problem and it throws this error before it reaches callback methods. As well found similar posts with same problem and it could be that it has something to do with gradle version I'm using `gradle:3.1.2` and retrofit `retrofit:2.4.0`

error:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x3ed6191f0 in tid 5897
```

Post method:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("url")
fun login(@Field("username") username: String, @Field("password") password: String): Call<LoginResponse>
```

Enqueue callback:

```
override fun login(email: String, password: String, callback: LogInDataSource.LogInCallback) {
    loginService.login(email, password).enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
            callback.onLoginFailed()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginResponse>?, response: Response<LoginResponse>?) {
            if (response?.body() != null){
                callback.onLoginSuccess(response.body()!!)
            }else{
                callback.onLoginFailed()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

LoginResponse data class:

```
data class LoginResponse(var token: String = "")
```

Response:

```
{
"token": "adasdasdfdsf",
"user_email": "asdasd@gmail.com",
"user_nicename": "asdasdgmail-com",
"user_display_name": "asdasd@gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: paste full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that problem was caused by instant run, disabling instant run fixed the problem